# How to change value in XML from another file with PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have config. I need to change values of value in a config having received value from the text file.
That is: the XML file has a `<add key='shopId' value='foo'/>` and a text file, it has a value.

I have replaced either the entire file, or prescribed duplicate value, or changed to the value that is specified in the variable, but not from a text file.

I do

```bsh
[XML]$xml = Get-Content "C:\Folder\config"
$xpath = "/configuration/appSettings/add[@value='5' and @key ='shopId']"
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes($xpath)

foreach ($n in $nodes) {
    $n.value = "TEST"   # How to change value from another file?
}

$xml.Save($xmlFile)
```

But it's not correct for me. Please help me. How to change value from another file?

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're facing. Does assigning the value not work? Are you asking how to read text from a file? Something else entirely? Are you getting errors? If so, what do they say?

Comment: Yes, i don't rewrite value from my text file. If i put $n.value = "1, or another", config file is update,  but does not take the values from my text file.

Comment: I would like to rewrite value from my text file.

Comment: `$n.value = "TEST"` -> `$n.value = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\file.txt'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to read the value from a text file and insert it into your XML configuration file.

### MWE

```
$TextFile = "C:\Folder\file.txt"
$XMLFile  = "C:\Folder\config.xml"

$Value    = Get-Content -Path $TextFile -Raw
[XML]$XML = Get-Content -Path $XMLFile
$XPath    = "/configuration/appSettings/add[@value='5' and @key ='shopId']"
$Nodes    = $XML.SelectNodes($xpath)

foreach ($Node in $Nodes) {
    $Node.value = $Value
}

$XML.Save($XMLFile)
```

Comment: Cannot set "value" because only strings can be used as values
 to set XmlNode properties.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed.

Comment: @ArtemKiryanov Please mark this as the answer, if it resolved your problem.